# SupportedOSPlatformAttribute on a property setter or getter

Tags: c#, cross-platform, compiler-warnings

Some properties have a getter which is available on all platforms, but their setter is only available on certain platforms, (and vis versa). For example, `Console.WindowWidth.get` is available on all platforms, but `Console.WindowWidth.set` is only available on windows.

I'm creating a simple class that wraps around certain Console properties, and am wondering how I can tell the compiler that the setter is only available on Windows, but the getter is available on all platforms.

My property is as follows:

```cs
public int WindowWidth
{
    get => Console.WindowWidth;
    set => Console.WindowWidth = value; // <-- warning
}
```

This gives me a warning:

> This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Console.WindowWidth.set' is only supported on: 'windows'.

I can add the [`SupportedOSPlatformAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.supportedosplatformattribute.-ctor?view=net-7.0) to the entire property, but this means it'll apply to the getter as well, which is something I dont want - I should be able to get the WindowWidth regardless of the OS:

```cs
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public int WindowWidth
{
    get => Console.WindowWidth;
    set => Console.WindowWidth = value; 
}

if (!OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
    var width = WindowWidth; // <-- warning
}
```

How can I specify that *only* the setter requires Windows, without affecting the getter? I thought maybe I could add the attribute on the setter, but while this is valid (i.e. compiles), it has no effect.

```cs
public int WindowWidth
{
    get => Console.WindowWidth;
    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    set => Console.WindowWidth = value; // <-- warning
}
```

---

I can work around this by changing my approach slightly as below and having different members for getting and setting, but I'm curious if/how this can be achieved.

Alternative approach:

```cs
public int WindowWidth
{
    get => Console.WindowWidth;
}

[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public void SetWindowWidth(int width)
{
    Console.WindowWidth = width;
}
```